# Есть ли готовые технологии, позволяющие создать веб интерфейс, без изучения javascript?

Tags: интерфейс

Основные требования:
Пользователь:

- Поддержка работы с таблицами
- Авторизация

Сервер:
БД - MYSQL

Желательно, чтобы код был на PHP

Какая задача стоит передо мной:

1. Пользователи должны авторизовываться
2. Интерфейс, где пользователи могут работать с таблицами, при этом не нужно будет описывать каждую форму, класс и прочее.
3. Создание отдельных страниц для обработки информации и взаимодействия с MYSQL

Все это при взаимодействии с MYSQL

Я пробовала написать все с нуля используя бутстрап, но это очень долго. Приходилось много костылей делать, что затрудняет разработку. ПЛЮС - ограничение по времени, около 2 месяцев.

Проблема в том, что не знаю javascript, что усложняет процесс, а учить его из-за 10-20 скриптов не рентабельно.

**ВОПРОС:**
Подскажите, есть ли готовые технологии, позволяющие создать веб интерфейс, без изучения javascript?

Comment: Похоже на попытку сколхозить phpMyAdmin на коленке. Чем вам не угодил оригинал?

Comment: Немного не поняли меня. Мне нужно создать интерфейс, используя MYSQL + PHP с возможностью в браузере использовать функционал таблиц. Т.е. ввод, вывод данных, редактирование, групповое изменение, добавление кнопок и.т.д. Полноценный интерфейс без использования javascript.

Comment: Понимаете, на слове "таблица" слишком много смысла.
-это может быть таблица в БД
-это может быть электронная таблица с формулами и вычислениями
-это может быть просто таблица.

В зависимости от того, что за задачу вы решаете, ответ будет разным.